# JPA with QueryDSL select query incorrect result

Tags: java, spring, jpa, querydsl

I have a problem when making a select to a table in a database, the data resulting from it is incorrect. Can there be some kind of Spring cache to update?

```
@Service
public class CronogramaService {

    @Autowired
    private CronogramaRepository cronogramaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Cronograma> findAll() {
        QCronograma cronograma = QCronograma.cronograma;
        return new JPAQuery(entityManager)
            .from(cronograma)
            .list(cronograma);
    }
}
```

Test main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_config.xml");

    CronogramaService cronoService = context.getBean(CronogramaService.class);

    List<Cronograma> crono = cronoService.findAll();

    for (Cronograma cronograma : crono) {
        System.out.println(cronograma.getDia());
        System.out.println(cronograma.getIdCronograma());
    }

    System.out.println();

    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)context).close();
}
```

The application has 365 days of the year 2018. But the result in id 1 returns me the day 2017-12-31. In the database the data of id 1 is 01-01-2018, and I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: There is nothing Spring Data JPA related in your code, so how can it be related to that? It is just plain JPA with QueryDSL... Also don't use `@Autowired` for the `EntityManager` you must use `@PersistenceContext` like in a regular application`.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for answering, I just updated the thread with more information.

Comment: Still nothing to do with Spring Data JPA and you are using JPA in a wrong way (as stated in my earlier comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar issue which boiled down to different timezones between application server and database server. Assuming you're using MySQL, try connecting to your database with the serverTimezone parameter set like jdbc:mysql://server:3306/database?serverTimezone=Europe/London

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a problem of time zone, I solved it with the time zone of my server America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires